# Memory leakage or deadlock when reusing a python multiprocessing pool within a loop

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, race-condition, pool

I have a large global variable that I process using a read-only operation. Each process generates a random subsample from the variable. I process the subsamples within a loop, then regenerate a new set of subsamples. So the code looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import dill

large_global_var = dill.load(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def gen_sample():
        subsample = some_sampling_strategy(large_global_var)
        return subsample

    pool = mp.Pool(100)

    def gen_batch_samples(pool):
        return pool.apply_async(gen_sample)

    jobs = gen_batch_samples(pool)

    for _ in range(1000):
        subsamples = [job.get() for job in jobs()]
        # do something with subsamples
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool = mp.Pool(100)
        jobs = gen_batch_samples(pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The above script always runs into a deadlock and freezes on the second iteration of the loop.

For references, I've tested this on `python 3.7` and `3.8` with the same results.

Below are the solutions I've tried and having worked:

1. Remove the nested `close` and `join` operations and reuse the pool (runs out of memory after a few iterations of the loop).
2. Use method 1 and explicitly delete all subsamples after each iteration.
3. Replace `apply_async` with `map` and have a self-contained pooling and sampling operation in `gen_batch_samples` (create and destroy the pool in that function).
4. Use a context manager instead of `close` and `join`.
5. Move the global variable and the sampling methods inside and outside the `main` method.
6. Pass the global variable as an argument to the `gen_batch_samples` and `gen_sample` methods.

Comment: First curiosity is that you re-create your pool In every loop. That doesn't make much sense. So I would move the `pool = mp.Pool(100)` outside of your for-loop and, secondly, just call the `apply_async`directly - not via the `gen_batch_samples`-function. That is unnecessarily folded.

Comment: Regarding moving the pool generation outside the loop, that's what I meant by solution #1. it resolved the deadlock but now I run out of memory. Applying the `gen_batch_samples` directly doesn't seem to help. Something is accumulating in the memory but I can't seem to locate it. There are a bunch of `numpy` and `torch` operations inside the sampling procedure, so perhaps that's where things go wrong.

Comment: I had a similar issue quite recently. There it was a RandomForest-Classifier where I didn't limit the tree size. So the it kept growing until hitting the memory limit. Unfortunately, multi-processing algorithms are hard to debug memory wise. You could try `memory_profiler` to check which of the processes is actually consuming your memory. Besides that you would likely have to check the torch stuff.